# Eclipse||JSTL Core Tags || behaviour

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jstl

I am new to JSP and at beginner stage. While I was coding a JSP using JSTL core tags I found that the core tags were not Identified, eventually I ended up here found that need to Add the JSTL jar. I did that. That Didn't Solve the Problem. I changed the first two lines of the JSP with :

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> . it did work.

My question is why does it work everytime i add the jar and re-paste the abv lines post that. Why not induviually.

Answer (score 0):

Using a tag library requires that it 1) be present locally and 2) have a directive in the JSP telling the server how to find it and to process it as part of generating your page's output.